# Post message on yammer using console application

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2012, yammer

I am new to JavaScript and c#. I am trying to post a message on yammer using REST API. I was able to do same using web application. However I am not able to do same using console application. Can anyone help with good example?

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between console and web application in this context is, you'd need to pre-obtain an access token for a console application.

See https://developer.yammer.com/docs/test-token

Once you've obtained a token, you can then pass it as a Bearer token in the Authorization Header of your POST request.